# Performance of Fortran versus MPI files writing/reading

Tags: optimization, file-io, fortran, mpi

I am confused about the performance of Fortran writing and reading performance (speed) versus MPI one for small and big files.

I wrote the following simple dummy program to test this (just writing dummy values to files):

```
PROGRAM test
! 
IMPLICIT NONE
! 
#if defined (__MPI)
        !
        !     Include file for MPI
        !
#if defined (__MPI_MODULE)
        USE mpi
#else
        INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
#endif
#else
        ! dummy world and null communicator
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MPI_COMM_WORLD =  0
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MPI_COMM_NULL  = -1
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MPI_COMM_SELF  = -2
#endif

INTEGER (kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: lsize, pos, pos2

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = 8
REAL(kind=DP), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: trans_prob, array_cpu
INTEGER ::  ierr, i, error, my_pool_id, world_comm
INTEGER (kind=DP) :: fil
REAL :: start, finish
INTEGER :: iunepmat, npool, arr_size, loop, pos3, j
  real(dp):: dummy
  integer*8 :: unf_recl
integer :: ios, direct_io_factor, recl

iunepmat = 10000
arr_size = 102400
loop     = 500

! Initialize MPI
CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_DUP(MPI_COMM_WORLD, world_comm, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(world_comm,my_pool_id,error)


ALLOCATE(trans_prob(arr_size))
trans_prob(:) = 1.5d0

!Write using Fortran
CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm,error)
!
CALL cpu_time(start)
!
DO i=1, loop 
  ! This writes also info on the record length using a real with 4 bytes. 
  OPEN(unit=10+my_pool_id, form='unformatted', position='append', action='write')
  WRITE(10+my_pool_id ) trans_prob(:)
  CLOSE(unit=10+my_pool_id)
ENDDO

CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(world_comm, npool, error)

! Master collect and write
IF (my_pool_id==0) THEN
  INQUIRE (IOLENGTH=direct_io_factor) dummy
  unf_recl = direct_io_factor * int(arr_size * loop, kind=kind(unf_recl)) 
  ALLOCATE (array_cpu( arr_size * loop ))
  array_cpu(:) = 0.0d0
  OPEN(unit=100,file='merged.dat',form='unformatted', status='new', position='append', action='write')
  DO i=0, npool - 1
    OPEN(unit=10+i,form='unformatted', status ='old', access='direct', recl = unf_recl )
    READ(unit=10+i, rec=1) array_cpu(:)
    CLOSE(unit=10+i)
    WRITE(unit=100) array_cpu(:)
  ENDDO
  CLOSE(unit=100)
  DEALLOCATE (array_cpu)
ENDIF

call cpu_time(finish)

!Print time
CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm,error)
IF (my_pool_id==0) print*, ' Fortran time', finish-start

!Write using MPI
CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm,error)
!
CALL cpu_time(start)
! 
lsize = INT( arr_size , kind = MPI_OFFSET_KIND)
pos = 0
pos2 = 0
CALL MPI_FILE_OPEN(world_comm, 'MPI.dat',MPI_MODE_WRONLY + MPI_MODE_CREATE,MPI_INFO_NULL,iunepmat,ierr)
DO i=1, loop
  pos = pos2 + INT( arr_size * (my_pool_id),  kind = MPI_OFFSET_KIND ) * 8_MPI_OFFSET_KIND
  CALL MPI_FILE_SEEK(iunepmat, pos, MPI_SEEK_SET, ierr)
  CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(iunepmat, trans_prob, lsize, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
  pos2 = pos2 + INT( arr_size * (npool -1),  kind = MPI_OFFSET_KIND ) * 8_MPI_OFFSET_KIND
ENDDO
!
CALL MPI_FILE_CLOSE(iunepmat,ierr)
CALL cpu_time(finish)
 
CALL MPI_BARRIER(world_comm,error)
IF (my_pool_id==0) print*, ' MPI time', finish-start

DEALLOCATE (trans_prob)

END PROGRAM
```

The compilation is made with:

```
mpif90  -O3  -x f95-cpp-input -D__FFTW -D__MPI -D__SCALAPACK  test_mpi2.f90 -o a.x
```

and then run in parallel with 4 cores:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.x
```

I get the following results:

Loop size 1

array size 10,240,000

File size: 313 Mb

Fortran time  0.237030014 sec

MPI time  0.164155006 sec

---

Loop size 10

array size 1,024,000

File size: 313 Mb

Fortran time  0.242821991 sec

MPI time  0.172048002 sec

---

Loop size 100

array size 102,400

File size: 313 Mb

Fortran time  0.235879987 sec

MPI time   9.78289992E-02 sec

---

Loop size 50

array size 1,024,000

File size: 1.6G

Fortran time   1.60272002 sec

MPI time   3.40623116 sec

---

Loop size 500

array size 102,400

File size: 1.6G

Fortran time   1.44547606 sec

MPI time   3.38340592 sec

---

As you can see the performances of MPI degrade significantly for larger files. Is it possible to improve MPI performance for large files ?

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: What kind of hardware do you use? Does it have any parallel filesystem?

Comment: I did the calculation on my desktop (4 cores and one SSD).

Comment: If I correctly understand your program, the first case (Fortran) has each rank write into its own file, and then the (single) root rank write into the result file, whereas the second case (MPI) has each rank write into the same (shared) result file in parallel. Not quite an apple to apple comparison IMHO. Anyway, the MPI case should use `MPI_File_write_at_all()` in order to efficiently have all the tasks (seek and) write into the shared file.

Comment: I agree with Gilles. I will add that it is important to test it on the target platform. If you plan to do mainly simulations on your cluster than test it there with the appropriate number of nodes and processes. If it is for your local desktop, than you are fine.

Comment: It's also probably relevant that you are asking the MPI code to do repeated seeks, while the Fortran code just blasts arrays into the file. Appropriate use of derived type might help you avoid this

Comment: The suggestion of Gilles helps a lot indeed. Thanks a lot.  By replacing the MPI_SEEK and MPI_WRITE call by one call to  MPI_File_write_at_all I get a nice speedup for the last case from 3.38 sec to only 1.96 sec. This is however still slower than 1.5 sec from direct Fortran writing. I also agree that it is not an apple to apple comparison but I need a single big file at the end.